# Unity IAP Subscription Not Purchasing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I am Using Unity IAP to Purchase Products using Consumables and Non-Consumables for a long time, but client has decided to use subscription also in the Project.

Since I was using Unity IAP I thought, that the best approach would be use it for subscription as well, I implemented the Subscription requirements in my current Purchaser Class as Following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;

using UnityEngine.Purchasing.Security;


/// <summary>
/// An example of Unity IAP functionality.
/// To use with your account, configure the product ids (AddProduct).
/// </summary>
[AddComponentMenu("Unity IAP/Demo")]
public class IAPDemo : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener
{
    // Unity IAP objects
    private IStoreController m_Controller;

    private IAppleExtensions m_AppleExtensions;
    private ISamsungAppsExtensions m_SamsungExtensions;
    private IMicrosoftExtensions m_MicrosoftExtensions;
    private ITransactionHistoryExtensions m_TransactionHistoryExtensions;
    private IGooglePlayStoreExtensions m_GooglePlayStoreExtensions;

#pragma warning disable 0414
    private bool m_IsGooglePlayStoreSelected;
#pragma warning restore 0414
    private bool m_IsSamsungAppsStoreSelected;

    private bool m_PurchaseInProgress;

    private Dictionary<string, IAPDemoProductUI> m_ProductUIs = new Dictionary<string, IAPDemoProductUI>();

    //public GameObject productUITemplate;
    //public RectTransform contentRect;

    //public Button restoreButton;

    //public Text versionText;

#if RECEIPT_VALIDATION
    private CrossPlatformValidator validator;
#endif

    /// <summary>
    /// This will be called when Unity IAP has finished initialising.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        m_Controller = controller;
        m_AppleExtensions = extensions.GetExtension<IAppleExtensions>();
        m_SamsungExtensions = extensions.GetExtension<ISamsungAppsExtensions>();
        m_MicrosoftExtensions = extensions.GetExtension<IMicrosoftExtensions>();
        m_TransactionHistoryExtensions = extensions.GetExtension<ITransactionHistoryExtensions>();
        m_GooglePlayStoreExtensions = extensions.GetExtension<IGooglePlayStoreExtensions>();
        // Sample code for expose product sku details for google play store
        // Key is product Id (Sku), value is the skuDetails json string
        //Dictionary<string, string> google_play_store_product_SKUDetails_json = m_GooglePlayStoreExtensions.GetProductJSONDictionary();
        // Sample code for manually finish a transaction (consume a product on GooglePlay store)
        //m_GooglePlayStoreExtensions.FinishAdditionalTransaction(productId, transactionId);

        //InitUI(controller.products.all);

        // On Apple platforms we need to handle deferred purchases caused by Apple's Ask to Buy feature.
        // On non-Apple platforms this will have no effect; OnDeferred will never be called.
        m_AppleExtensions.RegisterPurchaseDeferredListener(OnDeferred);

#if SUBSCRIPTION_MANAGER
        Dictionary<string, string> introductory_info_dict = m_AppleExtensions.GetIntroductoryPriceDictionary();
#endif
        // Sample code for expose product sku details for apple store
        //Dictionary<string, string> product_details = m_AppleExtensions.GetProductDetails();


        Debug.Log("Available items:");
        foreach (var item in controller.products.all)
        {
            if (item.availableToPurchase)
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Join(" |-| ",
                    new[]
                    {
                        item.metadata.localizedTitle,
                        item.metadata.localizedDescription,
                        item.metadata.isoCurrencyCode,
                        item.metadata.localizedPrice.ToString(),
                        item.metadata.localizedPriceString,
                        item.transactionID,
                        item.receipt
                    }));
#if INTERCEPT_PROMOTIONAL_PURCHASES
                // Set all these products to be visible in the user's App Store according to Apple's Promotional IAP feature
                // https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/PromotingIn-AppPurchases/PromotingIn-AppPurchases.html
                m_AppleExtensions.SetStorePromotionVisibility(item, AppleStorePromotionVisibility.Show);
#endif

#if SUBSCRIPTION_MANAGER
                // this is the usage of SubscriptionManager class
                if (item.receipt != null)
                {
                    if (item.definition.type == ProductType.Subscription)
                    {
                        if (checkIfProductIsAvailableForSubscriptionManager(item.receipt))
                        {
                            string intro_json = (introductory_info_dict == null || !introductory_info_dict.ContainsKey(item.definition.storeSpecificId)) ? null : introductory_info_dict[item.definition.storeSpecificId];
                            SubscriptionManager p = new SubscriptionManager(item, intro_json);
                            SubscriptionInfo info = p.getSubscriptionInfo();
                            Debug.Log("product id is: " + info.getProductId());
                            Debug.Log("purchase date is: " + info.getPurchaseDate());
                            Debug.Log("subscription next billing date is: " + info.getExpireDate());
                            Debug.Log("is subscribed? " + info.isSubscribed().ToString());
                            Debug.Log("is expired? " + info.isExpired().ToString());
                            Debug.Log("is cancelled? " + info.isCancelled());
                            Debug.Log("product is in free trial peroid? " + info.isFreeTrial());
                            Debug.Log("product is auto renewing? " + info.isAutoRenewing());
                            Debug.Log("subscription remaining valid time until next billing date is: " + info.getRemainingTime());
                            Debug.Log("is this product in introductory price period? " + info.isIntroductoryPricePeriod());
                            Debug.Log("the product introductory localized price is: " + info.getIntroductoryPrice());
                            Debug.Log("the product introductory price period is: " + info.getIntroductoryPricePeriod());
                            Debug.Log("the number of product introductory price period cycles is: " + info.getIntroductoryPricePeriodCycles());
                        } else
                        {
                            Debug.Log("This product is not available for SubscriptionManager class, only products that are purchase by 1.19+ SDK can use this class.");
                        }
                    } else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("the product is not a subscription product");
                    }
                } else
                {
                    Debug.Log("the product should have a valid receipt");
                }
#endif
            }
        }

        // Populate the product menu now that we have Products
        //AddProductUIs(m_Controller.products.all);

        LogProductDefinitions();
    }

#if SUBSCRIPTION_MANAGER
    private bool checkIfProductIsAvailableForSubscriptionManager(string receipt) {
        var receipt_wrapper = (Dictionary<string, object>)MiniJson.JsonDecode(receipt);
        if (!receipt_wrapper.ContainsKey("Store") || !receipt_wrapper.ContainsKey("Payload")) {
            Debug.Log("The product receipt does not contain enough information");
            return false;
        }
        var store = (string)receipt_wrapper ["Store"];
        var payload = (string)receipt_wrapper ["Payload"];

        if (payload != null ) {
            switch (store) {
            case GooglePlay.Name:
                {
                    var payload_wrapper = (Dictionary<string, object>)MiniJson.JsonDecode(payload);
                    if (!payload_wrapper.ContainsKey("json")) {
                        Debug.Log("The product receipt does not contain enough information, the 'json' field is missing");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var original_json_payload_wrapper = (Dictionary<string, object>)MiniJson.JsonDecode((string)payload_wrapper["json"]);
                    if (original_json_payload_wrapper == null || !original_json_payload_wrapper.ContainsKey("developerPayload")) {
                        Debug.Log("The product receipt does not contain enough information, the 'developerPayload' field is missing");
                        return false;
                    }
                    var developerPayloadJSON = (string)original_json_payload_wrapper["developerPayload"];
                    var developerPayload_wrapper = (Dictionary<string, object>)MiniJson.JsonDecode(developerPayloadJSON);
                    if (developerPayload_wrapper == null || !developerPayload_wrapper.ContainsKey("is_free_trial") || !developerPayload_wrapper.ContainsKey("has_introductory_price_trial")) {
                        Debug.Log("The product receipt does not contain enough information, the product is not purchased using 1.19 or later");
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            case AppleAppStore.Name:
            case AmazonApps.Name:
            case MacAppStore.Name:
                {
                    return true;
                }
            default:
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
#endif

    /// <summary>
    /// This will be called when a purchase completes.
    /// </summary>
    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Purchase Successful OK: " + e.purchasedProduct.definition.id);
        Debug.Log("Receipt: " + e.purchasedProduct.receipt);

        m_PurchaseInProgress = false;

#if RECEIPT_VALIDATION // Local validation is available for GooglePlay, and Apple stores
        if (m_IsGooglePlayStoreSelected ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.tvOS) {
            try {
                var result = validator.Validate(e.purchasedProduct.receipt);
                Debug.Log("Receipt is valid. Contents:");
                foreach (IPurchaseReceipt productReceipt in result) {
                    Debug.Log(productReceipt.productID);
                    Debug.Log(productReceipt.purchaseDate);
                    Debug.Log(productReceipt.transactionID);

                    GooglePlayReceipt google = productReceipt as GooglePlayReceipt;
                    if (null != google) {
                        Debug.Log(google.purchaseState);
                        Debug.Log(google.purchaseToken);
                    }

                    AppleInAppPurchaseReceipt apple = productReceipt as AppleInAppPurchaseReceipt;
                    if (null != apple) {
                        Debug.Log(apple.originalTransactionIdentifier);
                        Debug.Log(apple.subscriptionExpirationDate);
                        Debug.Log(apple.cancellationDate);
                        Debug.Log(apple.quantity);
                    }

                    // For improved security, consider comparing the signed
                    // IPurchaseReceipt.productId, IPurchaseReceipt.transactionID, and other data
                    // embedded in the signed receipt objects to the data which the game is using
                    // to make this purchase.
                }
            } catch (IAPSecurityException ex) {
                Debug.Log("Invalid receipt, not unlocking content. " + ex);
                return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
            }
        }
#endif

        // Unlock content from purchases here.
#if USE_PAYOUTS
        if (e.purchasedProduct.definition.payouts != null) {
            Debug.Log("Purchase complete, paying out based on defined payouts");
            foreach (var payout in e.purchasedProduct.definition.payouts) {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("Granting {0} {1} {2} {3}", payout.quantity, payout.typeString, payout.subtype, payout.data));
            }
        }
#endif
        // Indicate if we have handled this purchase.
        //   PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete: ProcessPurchase will not be called
        //     with this product again, until next purchase.
        //   PurchaseProcessingResult.Pending: ProcessPurchase will be called
        //     again with this product at next app launch. Later, call
        //     m_Controller.ConfirmPendingPurchase(Product) to complete handling
        //     this purchase. Use to transactionally save purchases to a cloud
        //     game service.
#if DELAY_CONFIRMATION
        StartCoroutine(ConfirmPendingPurchaseAfterDelay(e.purchasedProduct));
        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Pending;
#else
        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
#endif
    }

#if DELAY_CONFIRMATION
    private HashSet<string> m_PendingProducts = new HashSet<string>();

    private IEnumerator ConfirmPendingPurchaseAfterDelay(Product p)
    {
        m_PendingProducts.Add(p.definition.id);
        Debug.Log("Delaying confirmation of " + p.definition.id + " for 5 seconds.");

        var end = Time.time + 5f;

        while (Time.time < end) {
            yield return null;
            var remaining = Mathf.CeilToInt (end - Time.time);
            UpdateProductPendingUI (p, remaining);
        }

        if (m_IsGooglePlayStoreSelected)
        {
            Debug.Log("Is " + p.definition.id + " currently owned, according to the Google Play store? "
                      + m_GooglePlayStoreExtensions.IsOwned(p));
        }
        Debug.Log("Confirming purchase of " + p.definition.id);
        m_Controller.ConfirmPendingPurchase(p);
        m_PendingProducts.Remove(p.definition.id);
        UpdateProductUI (p);
    }
#endif

    /// <summary>
    /// This will be called if an attempted purchase fails.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product item, PurchaseFailureReason r)
    {
        Debug.Log("Purchase failed: " + item.definition.id);
        Debug.Log(r);

        // Detailed debugging information
        Debug.Log("Store specific error code: " + m_TransactionHistoryExtensions.GetLastStoreSpecificPurchaseErrorCode());
        if (m_TransactionHistoryExtensions.GetLastPurchaseFailureDescription() != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Purchase failure description message: " +
                      m_TransactionHistoryExtensions.GetLastPurchaseFailureDescription().message);
        }

        m_PurchaseInProgress = false;
    }

    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        Debug.Log("Billing failed to initialize!");
        switch (error)
        {
            case InitializationFailureReason.AppNotKnown:
                Debug.LogError("Is your App correctly uploaded on the relevant publisher console?");
                break;
            case InitializationFailureReason.PurchasingUnavailable:
                // Ask the user if billing is disabled in device settings.
                Debug.Log("Billing disabled!");
                break;
            case InitializationFailureReason.NoProductsAvailable:
                // Developer configuration error; check product metadata.
                Debug.Log("No products available for purchase!");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Awake()
    {
        var module = StandardPurchasingModule.Instance();

        // The FakeStore supports: no-ui (always succeeding), basic ui (purchase pass/fail), and
        // developer ui (initialization, purchase, failure code setting). These correspond to
        // the FakeStoreUIMode Enum values passed into StandardPurchasingModule.useFakeStoreUIMode.
        module.useFakeStoreUIMode = FakeStoreUIMode.StandardUser;

        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(module);

        // Set this to true to enable the Microsoft IAP simulator for local testing.
        builder.Configure<IMicrosoftConfiguration>().useMockBillingSystem = false;

        m_IsGooglePlayStoreSelected =
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android && module.appStore == AppStore.GooglePlay;

#if AGGRESSIVE_INTERRUPT_RECOVERY_GOOGLEPLAY
        // For GooglePlay, if we have access to a backend server to deduplicate purchases, query purchase history
        // when attempting to recover from a network-interruption encountered during purchasing. Strongly recommend
        // deduplicating transactions across app reinstallations because this relies upon the on-device, deletable
        // TransactionLog database.
        builder.Configure<IGooglePlayConfiguration>().aggressivelyRecoverLostPurchases = true;
        // Use purchaseToken instead of orderId for all transactions to avoid non-unique transactionIDs for a
        // single purchase; two ProcessPurchase calls for one purchase, differing only by which field of the receipt
        // is used for the Product.transactionID. Automatically true if aggressivelyRecoverLostPurchases is enabled
        // and this API is not called at all.
        builder.Configure<IGooglePlayConfiguration>().UsePurchaseTokenForTransactionId(true);
#endif

        // Define our products.
        // Either use the Unity IAP Catalog, or manually use the ConfigurationBuilder.AddProduct API.
        // Use IDs from both the Unity IAP Catalog and hardcoded IDs via the ConfigurationBuilder.AddProduct API.

        // Use the products defined in the IAP Catalog GUI.
        // E.g. Menu: "Window" > "Unity IAP" > "IAP Catalog", then add products, then click "App Store Export".
        var catalog = ProductCatalog.LoadDefaultCatalog();

        foreach (var product in catalog.allValidProducts)
        {
            if (product.allStoreIDs.Count > 0)
            {
                var ids = new IDs();
                foreach (var storeID in product.allStoreIDs)
                {
                    ids.Add(storeID.id, storeID.store);
                }
                builder.AddProduct(product.id, product.type, ids);
                print("Catalog 1 Prods id: " + product.id + " type: " + product.type);
            }
            else
            {
                builder.AddProduct(product.id, product.type);
                print("Catalog 2 Prods id: " + product.id + " type: " + product.type);
            }
        }

        // In this case our products have the same identifier across all the App stores,
        // except on the Mac App store where product IDs cannot be reused across both Mac and
        // iOS stores.
        // So on the Mac App store our products have different identifiers,
        // and we tell Unity IAP this by using the IDs class.

        //builder.AddProduct("android.test.purchased", ProductType.Consumable);

        //builder.AddProduct("com.test.weekly", ProductType.Subscription);


        // Write Amazon's JSON description of our products to storage when using Amazon's local sandbox.
        // This should be removed from a production build.
        //builder.Configure<IAmazonConfiguration>().WriteSandboxJSON(builder.products);

        // This enables simulated purchase success for Samsung IAP.
        // You would remove this, or set to SamsungAppsMode.Production, before building your release package.
        builder.Configure<ISamsungAppsConfiguration>().SetMode(SamsungAppsMode.AlwaysSucceed);
        // This records whether we are using Samsung IAP. Currently ISamsungAppsExtensions.RestoreTransactions
        // displays a blocking Android Activity, so:
        // A) Unity IAP does not automatically restore purchases on Samsung Galaxy Apps
        // B) IAPDemo (this) displays the "Restore" GUI button for Samsung Galaxy Apps
        m_IsSamsungAppsStoreSelected =
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android && module.appStore == AppStore.SamsungApps;

#if INTERCEPT_PROMOTIONAL_PURCHASES
        // On iOS and tvOS we can intercept promotional purchases that come directly from the App Store.
        // On other platforms this will have no effect; OnPromotionalPurchase will never be called.
        builder.Configure<IAppleConfiguration>().SetApplePromotionalPurchaseInterceptorCallback(OnPromotionalPurchase);
        Debug.Log("Setting Apple promotional purchase interceptor callback");
#endif

#if RECEIPT_VALIDATION
        string appIdentifier;
#if UNITY_5_6_OR_NEWER
        appIdentifier = Application.identifier;
#else
        appIdentifier = Application.bundleIdentifier;
#endif
        validator = new CrossPlatformValidator(GooglePlayTangle.Data(), AppleTangle.Data(), appIdentifier);
#endif

        // Now we're ready to initialize Unity IAP.
        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This will be called after a call to IAppleExtensions.RestoreTransactions().
    /// </summary>
    private void OnTransactionsRestored(bool success)
    {
        Debug.Log("Transactions restored." + success);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// iOS Specific.
    /// This is called as part of Apple's 'Ask to buy' functionality,
    /// when a purchase is requested by a minor and referred to a parent
    /// for approval.
    ///
    /// When the purchase is approved or rejected, the normal purchase events
    /// will fire.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Item.</param>
    private void OnDeferred(Product item)
    {
        Debug.Log("Purchase deferred: " + item.definition.id);
    }

#if INTERCEPT_PROMOTIONAL_PURCHASES
    private void OnPromotionalPurchase(Product item) {
        Debug.Log("Attempted promotional purchase: " + item.definition.id);

        // Promotional purchase has been detected. Handle this event by, e.g. presenting a parental gate.
        // Here, for demonstration purposes only, we will wait five seconds before continuing the purchase.
        StartCoroutine(ContinuePromotionalPurchases());
    }

    private IEnumerator ContinuePromotionalPurchases()
    {
        Debug.Log("Continuing promotional purchases in 5 seconds");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        Debug.Log("Continuing promotional purchases now");
        m_AppleExtensions.ContinuePromotionalPurchases (); // iOS and tvOS only; does nothing on Mac
    }
#endif



    public void PurchaseButtonClick(string productID)
    {
        if (m_PurchaseInProgress == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Please wait, purchase in progress");
            return;
        }

        if (m_Controller == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Purchasing is not initialized");
            return;
        }

        if (m_Controller.products.WithID(productID) == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No product has id " + productID);
            return;
        }

        // Don't need to draw our UI whilst a purchase is in progress.
        // This is not a requirement for IAP Applications but makes the demo
        // scene tidier whilst the fake purchase dialog is showing.
        m_PurchaseInProgress = true;

        //Sample code how to add accountId in developerPayload to pass it to getBuyIntentExtraParams
        //Dictionary<string, string> payload_dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //payload_dictionary["accountId"] = "Faked account id";
        //payload_dictionary["developerPayload"] = "Faked developer payload";
        //m_Controller.InitiatePurchase(m_Controller.products.WithID(productID), MiniJson.JsonEncode(payload_dictionary));
        Product product = m_Controller.products.WithID(productID);
        print("Buying: " + product.definition.id + " isAva: " + product.availableToPurchase + " allPro: " + m_Controller.products.all.Length);
        m_Controller.InitiatePurchase(m_Controller.products.WithID(productID));

    }

    public void RestoreButtonClick()
    {
        if (m_IsSamsungAppsStoreSelected)
        {
            m_SamsungExtensions.RestoreTransactions(OnTransactionsRestored);
        }
        else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WSAPlayerX86 ||
                 Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WSAPlayerX64 ||
                 Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WSAPlayerARM)
        {
            m_MicrosoftExtensions.RestoreTransactions();
        }
        else if (m_IsGooglePlayStoreSelected)
        {
            m_GooglePlayStoreExtensions.RestoreTransactions(OnTransactionsRestored);
        }
        else
        {
            m_AppleExtensions.RestoreTransactions(OnTransactionsRestored);
        }
    }

    private bool NeedRestoreButton()
    {
        return Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer ||
               Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer ||
               Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.tvOS ||
               Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WSAPlayerX86 ||
               Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WSAPlayerX64 ||
               Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WSAPlayerARM ||
               m_IsSamsungAppsStoreSelected;
    }

    private void LogProductDefinitions()
    {
        var products = m_Controller.products.all;
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
#if UNITY_5_6_OR_NEWER
            Debug.Log(string.Format("id: {0}\nstore-specific id: {1}\ntype: {2}\nenabled: {3}\n", product.definition.id, product.definition.storeSpecificId, product.definition.type.ToString(), product.definition.enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
#else
            Debug.Log(string.Format("id: {0}\nstore-specific id: {1}\ntype: {2}\n", product.definition.id,
                product.definition.storeSpecificId, product.definition.type.ToString()));
#endif
        }
    }
}

#endif // UNITY_PURCHASING
```

I created a Subscription ID on my Play Console, copied the ID from the console and pasted it in IAP Catalog, then I Created Receipt validator Obfuscator also.

Now When I Built the Project and checked the Logs, the Available Products showed me All three Products including the Subsciption, but when I Purchased the Subscription it would show me Error Saying:

BuyingFailed: Product (com.test.google.weekly) not available.

I dont know what am i doing wrong here, i tripple checked the IDs, Public API Key, and Keystore, all are OK, but always this is repeating

Answer (score 3):

In **Google play**, in order to test your IAP Subscription,

- Firstly, Publish your app to a test track. Note that after you publish an app to a testing track, it can take a few hours for the app to be available for testers.
- On your test’s opt-in URL, your testers will get an explanation of what it means to be a tester and a link to opt-in.
  **RTFM**: [Test Google Play Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test?authuser=1)